# EXT js beforeedit

Tags: extjs, grid

i have now another big question, i paste my code and i asked then my question

```
 var gridTablaConsulta = Ext.create('Ext.grid.GridPanel', {
    title:'Consulta Tabla lotes',
    id:'gridTabla',
    store: storeTabla,
    columns: [
        Ext.create('Ext.grid.RowNumberer'),
        {text: "NRBE", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'NRBE'},
        {text: "APLIC", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'APLIC'},
        {text: "FORM", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'FORM'},
        {text: "VERFOR", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'VERFOR'},
        {text: "FECLOT", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'FECLOT'},
        {text: "HORLOT", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'HORLOT'},
        {text: "TIPPAPLO", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'TIPPAPLO'},
        {text: "TAMPAP", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'TAMPAP'},
        {text: "FECINIIM", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'FECINIIM'},
        {text: "FECINIOB", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'FECINIOB',editor:     {xtype:'textfield', allowBlank:true}},
        {text: "ESTLOT", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex:'ESTLOT',editor:{xtype:'textfield', allowBlank:true}},
        {text: "TOTPAGGE", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'TOTPAGGE'},
        {text: "TOTPAGIM", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'TOTPAGIM'},
        {text: "DESLOT", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'DESLOT'},
        {text: "TIPDIF", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'TIPDIF'},
        {text: "DIADIF", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'DIADIF'},
        {text: "FECALT", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'FECALT'},
        {text: "FECMOD", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'FECMOD'},
        {text: "TERMOD", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'TERMOD'},
        {text: "HORMOD", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'HORMOD'}
    ],
    selType: 'rowmodel',
    plugins: [
        Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', {
            clicksToEdit: 2
        })
    ],

    listeners: {

        beforeedit: function(editor, e, eOpts) {
            var grid = Ext.getCmp('gridTabla'); // or e.grid
            if (e.record.data.ESTLOT === '02') {
                e.cancel = true; //no permite
            } else {
                e.cancel = false; //permite
            }
            if (e.record.data.ESTLOT === '01') {
                e.cancel = false; //no permite
            } 


        },

         edit: function(e, context){
             var record = context.record;
             var recordData = record.getData();
             recordData.Funcionalidad = 'Modificar';
             alert(JSON.stringify(recordData));
             Ext.Ajax.request({
                 url: 'http://localhost:8080/MyMaver/ServletTablaLotes',
                 method: 'POST',

                 // merge row data with other params
                 params: recordData
             });
         }
        }
});
```

Ok, now my question, the problem is that in my beforeedit, i need to check a condition that allow me to change the field "ESTLOT" to another value depens of the previous value, for example, if ESTLOT value is 04 and 05, in that field ESTLOT could be 01 or 03, but if the value is 06 or 03 it could be 04 or 05. My problem is that i dont know who to evaluated that kind of condition because in beforeedit i have the previous value but in edit i have the value changed...

Anyboby can help me? Thanks for all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a both values, you just don't know where they are: `e.value`, `e.originalValue`

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-event-beforeedit

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-event-edit